# Windows 10 Upg. Licensing: Can I move a system image repeatedly between multiple hosts?

Tags: windows-10, license, licensing, boot-to-vhd

I have several computers for different uses/locations, all licensed via the free Windows 10 upgrade program.  The hardware is quite similar and I would like to take the system image with me, without maintaining the different computers individually.  Booting of an vhdx image is easy enough.

Are the Windows 10 Upgrade licenses purely dependent on hardware, or will I run into trouble at some time, if the same image is continuously moved between different hardware and always tries to reactivate or similar.

eg. Is there some kind of an counter where the system notices that the current hardware does not correspond to the last activated hardware and a threshold where it locks up after x activations.

Comment: Winows 10 in general is licensed by hardware. The only exception would be retail licenses, they can be moved around, same as always.  The motherboard is consider the primary factor, this fact, is well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound my question is not of theoratical nature. All hosts are licensed by upgrade and already were activated at some point. My question in simple terms is what happens when using only one harddisk for all hosts by physically taking it from one host to another. Will windows deny working or display a nasty message at some time?  Syncing is not an option.